# How to make sure a button click is process by a webpage before continuing with automation selenium

Tags: c#, vb.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to automate the login process to a webpage using selenium and chrome driver. The webpage login button element looks like this;

```
<div class="button small"><a class="btn-login" href="#">Login</a></div>
```

So I click it using the following;

```
bot.FindElement(By.LinkText("Login")).Click()
```

Where 'bot' is my chrome driver. This works, 100% of the time it clicks the button. I'd now like to automate the next step of the processes but here's where I hit a snag. Clicking the button doesn't load a new webpage, it just runs a script on the page where I need to click another button (basically select what area I want to log into). How can I wait until the webpage has processed the first click so I can process the next click. When I try the next click I get this error;

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'unknown error: Element <a class="area-select" href="/page/area/start">...</a> is not clickable at point (542, 318). Other element would receive the click: <div class="right login">...</div>


 (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)'
```

I don't really know what this error means. It looks like it's saying the button I want to click isn't clickable (but I can manually click it in the browser) so I assume it means the element isn't activated when I send the command? If so how can I wait until this?

Comment: When I've needed to do a similar thing, I've found that telling the thread to sleep for a small while (maybe a second or so) before continuing usually works. You could also try a do-while, but make sure that what you're doing isn't resource intensive.

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert some hard wait or apply some implicit wait for that particular element befire clicking

Answer (score 0):

Plz try the below code. It will include an implicit wait until the link you trying to click becomes enable/clickable:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
{
 IWebElement element = d.FindElement(By.Id("myid"));
 if (element.Displayed && element.Enabled)
{
    return element;
}

return null;
});
```